# android : issue in playing youtube videos in webview

Tags: android, webview, youtube

My code to play vide is below. In onlt HTC phone, i am getting the error

"webpage not available

web page at  **data:text/html;%20charset=UTF-8;null,%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%3C/head%3E%3Cbody%20style=%22margin:%200;%20padding:%200%22%3E%3Ciframe%20type=%22text/html%22%20class=%22youtube-player%22%20width=%22300%22%20height=%22100%%22%20src=%22http**

it is working on other devices.

Why the video link is not coming right way only for this device while other devices intepret it right
Or is it some other issues . Please help

```
String data = "<html>"
                + "<head>"
                + "</head>"
                + "<body style=\"margin: 0; padding: 0\">"
                + "<iframe "
                + "type=\"text/html\" "
                + "class=\"youtube-player\" "
                + "width=\""
                + width
                + "\" "
                + "height=\""
                + height
                + "\" "
                + "src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/"
                + videoid
                + "?controls=0&showinfo=0&showsearch=0&modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&fs=0\" "
                + "frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>" + "</body>" + "</html>";

webReview.loadData(data,
                        "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```